# Ubuntu 22.04.2 command "pyenv" not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyenv

I'm brand new at this and am trying to download Python. I can get to:

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

But as soon as I enter the last line, I get the error:

```
Command 'pyenv' not found, did you mean:
  command 'p7env' from deb libnss3-tools (2:3.68.2-0ubuntu1.
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled with `rm -rf ~/.pyenv` several times and tried adjusting the problem line to `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` on recommendation from the system assist for my program with no change. I'm hitting the same error at the same point in the process every time.

I need to get Python 3.8.

I have uninstalled the saved files multiple times and made adjustments to the code lines, changing:

```
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

To:

```
"$(pyenv init -)"
```

without any change.

I'm following directions provided by my bootcamp to set up my virtual environment and have also tried to follow the source from Github and the installation wiki linked there.

Comment: You have to install `pyenv` after installation of Python.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg `pyenv` doesn't appear to be available as an Ubuntu package, at least from the default sources. https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: @KeithThompson Just wondering if OP got his shell code from default source or not.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Actually you want to install `pyenv` _before_ Python (though of course Ubuntu already includes Python because the OS depends on it); one of the crucial features of `pyenv` is that installs Python versions for you on demand.

Answer (score 1):

The error messages simply mean that `pyenv` is not installed on your computer, and thus needs to be installed before you can use it.

Here are some brief instructions for how to do that; but it seems that you have a fairly steep learning curve ahead of you if your bootcamp instructor assumes you are able to pull this off without help.

```
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
```

fetches and runs a simple script (you obviously need to have `curl` installed, which fortunately you can install with `sudo apt-get install -y curl`).

It will print some additional instructions for you to follow, but those should be manageable (basically, adding the lines you were already trying to use to your shell's startup file).

Once you have `pyenv` installed and configured for your shell, you probably want to set it up to manage at least one Python version for you (though note that Ubuntu already ships with `python` installed out of the box, albeit probably not the version you want -- Ubuntu Jammy ships with Python 3.10, and you have to use `python3` instead of `python` to run it. Ubuntu Focal aka 20.04 ships with Python 3.8).

```
pyenv install 3.8
```

for example to install Python 3.8. Maybe you also want to set it as your default Python version with

```
pyenv global 3.8
```

See also https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv for a fuller treatment of `pyenv` and its facilities.